# kivy python buttonbehavior on_press disable

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to build an app using kivy. I have added close button and then I added `on_release`. However, pressing the button does not work.

python code:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.11.0')
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.core.window import Window


Window.size = (350 * 1.5 , 600 * 1.5)
with open("./template.kv", encoding='utf8') as f:
    Builder.load_string(f.read())

class CloseButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CloseButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.source = './close_btn@2x.png'
    always_release = True

    def on_press(self):
        App.get_running_app().stop()

class Background(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Background, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class TemplateApp(App):
    def build(self):
        # title bar remove
        # Window.borderless = True
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(Background(name='back'))
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TemplateApp().run()
```

kivy code:

```
<Background>:
    canvas:

        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: "background.png"
    Label:
        font_size: 12 * 1.5
        text: 'Template'
        font_name: './NotoSans-hinted/NotoSans-Regular.ttf'
        size_hint: (1.0, 1.0)
        halign: "left"
        valign: "top"
        color: 0.43568, 0.43568, 0.43568, 1
        text_size: root.width - (40 * 1.5), 583 * 1.5

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1.9, 1.938
        CloseButton:
            id: close_btn
```

Comment: Removed unnecessary words and formatting from the question to make it more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
    def on_press(self):
        App.get_running_app().stop()
```

try this

```
self.on_press = App.get_running_app().stop()
```

Ok, let's try this:

```
from kivy.clock import Clock
...
class CloseButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CloseButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.source = './close_btn@2x.png'
    # no parentheses after method's name!
    self.on_press = self.closeapp

    def closeapp(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(App.get_running_app().stop())
```

Comment: WARNING:kivy:stderr: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'stop'

I got this message T^T

Comment: I've added second solution, try it.